# unable to install software-center

Tags: 14.04, python, software-center

I'm trying to install software-center but for that it depends on python-lxml. I tried to install python-lxml using

```
apt-get install python-lxml
```

But got

```
It depends on python>= 2.7 but it is not going to be installed
Python<2.8 but it is not going to be installed
Python : any (>= 2.7.1- 0Ubuntu 2) 
Unable to correct problems , you have held broken packages
```

Comment: does adding this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa and running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing` solve it?

Comment: Software Center is already installed on Ubuntu 14.04. How did you get to this situation? Edit: Is this related to [your last question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1066755/301745), where you uninstalled Python 2.7? Cause this would be a side-effect of that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) available to get you the latest python:

**IF you are in recovery mode**

If you are in recovery mode you will need to do some things to make sure you can write to your drives, and any partitions are mounted. Per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361990/installing-software-in-recovery-mode):

> You can install software in the recovery mode, but there are a couple
> of things to keep in mind:
>
> - Only `/` is mounted, so if you have a separate /var, /usr, /home, you need to mount then yourself
> - Filesystems are mounted read-only, so you need to remount them using
>   `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`
> - Drivers for your network card or wireless interface may not be loaded

Be sure to run:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Before proceeding.

**Make sure your system is up to date**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Add the PPA**

MANUALLY, by adding the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

OR AUTOMATICALLY, if the following software is available, add it automatically:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

Now reload your repos and upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```

**Reinstall Python**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python
sudo ap-get autoremove autoclean
sudo apt-get install python
```

**Install Updated Python(s)**

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

This will get you the latest python and should solve your problem!

You might also want to install python 3 and/or the dev packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
sudo apt-get install python-dev python2.7-dev python3-dev
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82006/discussion-on-answer-by-joshua-besneatte-unable-to-install-software-center).